# NestJS for same Applicaiton to use multiple Connections using TypeORM module

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

We re-write an API to NestJS. However, due to a business logic older framework developers replicated the same code base each time. So itt is required to connect to multiple databases which contain similar tables. For example if one Database contains tables user,facilities and products then the other contains all of them too. In short everything is duplicate for each installation. Only the content of the databases is of course different.

Let's go to coding shall we? To prevent the duplication at least of the code base we tried to create named multiple connections, named after the company name i.e db_google,db_linkedin and a param in url that defines which connection to fetch from the pool

```
app.module.ts

imports: [
  TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'mysql',
    name: 'google',
    host: 'our_host_url',
    port: 3306,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db_google',
    entities: [Facility, FacilityCategory, Customer],
    synchronize: false,
  }),
  TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'mysql',
    name: 'linkedin',
    host: 'our_host_url',
    port: 3306,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db_linkedin',
    entities: [Facility, FacilityCategory, Customer],
    synchronize: false,

  }),
```

After this we import it to each module we need to fetch data from DB (almost every module import it)

```
customer.module.ts
imports: [
  TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Customer, Facility], 'db_google'),
  TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Customer, Facility], 'db_linkedin'),
],
```

To distinct databases in each [module].service.ts we use switch case and using the parameter from url to define which connection to use

```
customer.service.ts

constructor(
  @InjectDataSource('google')
  private dataSourceGoogle: DataSource,
  @InjectDataSource('linkedin')
  private dataSourceLinkedin: DataSource,
) {}

async findCustomer(
  username: string,
  companyName: string,
): Promise<Customer | null> {
  switch (companyName) {
    case 'apollohotels':
      return this.dataSourceGoogle.getRepository(Customer).findOneBy({
        username: username,
      });
    case 'saniresort':
      return this.dataSourceLinkedin.getRepository(Customer).findOneBy({
        username: username,
      });
  }
}
```

So we thought to prevent duplication code to create a module to import all these databases for example "ConnectionPool" module, and import it to each module that needs to fetch data from DB. And their service to return the correct datasource depending the companyName parameter. It is a good approach? Does it happen someone to have the same problem and find another better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess something you could do is create function that returns the correct dataSource, after that should be really easy to avoid code duplication.

```js
async findCustomer(
  username: string,
  companyName: string,
): Promise<Customer | null> {
  return this.getDataSource(companyName).getRepository(Customer)
    .findOneBy({
       username: username,
     });
}


getDataSource(companyName: string): DataSource {
  const dataSourceMap = {
    "apollohotels": this.dataSourceGoogle,
    "saniresort": this.dataSourceLinkedin
  }

  return dataSourceMap[companyName]
}
```